Export referenced DLL for other projects to use as well?
We have a NuGet package that comes from another solution and a repo that we reference in another project.
As it stands right now, our workflow is to develop things and as we find issues in the we'll go through the process of making the change, bumping the version number, making a PR, waiting for the branch to merge, wait for the CI/CD pipelines to build and publish the package and then wait a little longer for the package repository to update.
It's pretty annoying, the process eats up about 30 minutes and I got to thinking that it'd be really convenient to just develop the two side by side:
I could make my changes in both repos and then create two separate PRs that I know are good to go and would reduce the amount of tiny 2-3 liner PRs I send to my team to review.
I've been tinkering with it a bit in my free time because it's an interesting problem to try and solve, and here's what I have found so far. I have found I can do is something like this to achieve my goal:
<ItemGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="Exists('/path/to/local/package.dll')">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="My.Package">
          <HintPath>/path/to/local/package.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="My.Package" Version="9.9.9"
      </ItemGroup>      
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
</ItemGroup>

This works... except that it seems that when the project knows about the local version of the package that only that project knows about it.
So let's say in the consuming solution I have these projects:
|--- My.Project.BusinessLogic
|--- My.Project.Api
|------ References My.Project.BusinessLogic
|--- My.Project.Functions
|----- References My.Project.BusinessLogic

What happens is I can build My.Project.BusinessLogic just fine. It works as intended when it knows or doesn't know about the local project, however *.Api and *.Functions throws compiler errors when trying to reference the local project through My.Project.BusinessLogic because it doesn't know about My.Package for some reason.
I can get them building as well if I add this to each dependent project (and eliminates the need for multiple package references across the projects to be concerned about versions):
<ItemGroup Condition="Exists('/path/to/local/package.dll')">
  <Reference Include="/path/to/local/package.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

This isn't terrible, it gives me what I ultimately need, but I can't help but wonder if there's a way to tell My.Project.BusinessLogic that the DLL needs to be exported to the other projects when it builds.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
Edit:
I found something through ChatGPT that seems to have done the trick,
I added this statement below within the  tag, and then tested things work as I would expect and it seems to be doing exactly what I want!
<When Condition="Exists('/path/to/local/package.dll')">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="My.Package">
      <HintPath>/path/to/local/package.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
<!-- Rest of the xml snippet omitted for brevity -->

and as a bonus I added an additional check to the  condition to only enable this if I have a local environment variable set (as I suspect this will cause a lot of confusion to other developers if they have older versions of the dll built and have been relying on the nuget package):
<When Condition="'$(UseLocalMyPackageDll)' == 'true' and Exists('/path/to/local/package.dll')">

I'm still open to better solutions for this, but I think I achieved exactly what I wanted.

I was tinkering around with something similar. But my attempt was to have a Build-Mode (like "Release/Debug" - I'd have "Development" for example) dedicated to the "direct" development approach and if it is active, I'd have a Project Reference but for all other Build Modes, I'd have a Package Reference. Haven't got it to where the team could commit to it, though yet.

@Fildor that's interesting, and to manage package references, the developer would need to opt out of "development mode"? :) And this question was born out of another question: what is wrong with having package refs in dev mode? :)

There is nothing wrong with it inherently. And that's probably like we are going to keep it. I have been tasked to explore this only because some team members felt ... let's say "attached" to "the olden ways" and wouldn't bother to bump versions yadda yadda ... For me, it's a question of "do you fully commit to the nuget way of doing things?" - so as of today, my take-away from above mentioned exploration is: Just have packages and adjust your workflow. Having a hybrid solution may work for a small experimantal setup but in real life it probably introduces more problems than it solves. @Mich
